# How soon are credit reports available, after opening one's first credit account ?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit-report

They say that your credit reports are available after having an open credit account for 6 months. I've had a Citi Forward card for international students for 6 months and a week now, but I still can't get my online credit report.

Is this "6 months" a hard rule? Or should I be patient and wait a little bit more?

Comment: Was your Citi Forward card secured by a (cash) deposit? If not, did you have payslips of some kind to show them? I am assuming you do not have a pre-exisiting credit history in the US

Comment: Interesting. I'd never heard this. But it does make sense that there would be a delay for new reports, even so, 6 months seems quite a while.

Comment: It was an unsecured card for international college students with no pre-existing credit history. What do you mean by a payslip? I went paperless and all my transactions have been online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call Citi and ask them if they even reported you to the agencies. Agencies won't create a report if no-one put anything on it. Once the data starts accumulating, it will take several months till the agencies will score you (that's what the "6-months rule" refers to).

Comment: Some lenders do not report cards secured by a (cash) deposit. OP did not answer my question to that effect, but I am pretty sure CRAs have reports available as soon as a lender reports to them. Equifax is an exception and they explicitly mention this 6 month  rule somewhere (I forget) as afar as their report is concerned. Scoring could be a different matter, and they might want a min number of data points to score you with.

Comment: It was an unsecured card, but I'll take your advice and still ask if they've reported me to the agencies! I'll update you guys once I get an answer.

Comment: It seems that they have been reporting my activities every month, yet every agency seems to be unable to verify me online. I think I should try the offline option.

Answer (score 2):

That 6 months rule applies only to Equifax I believe. I was able to grab my Transunion report the next month after my first credit card, and the Experian report the month after that.

That was 6 months ago.

I have been asking Equifax for my score and they just told me I have a score from them (I could not get any till now), which means they don't score anyone less than 6 months of history, but the other two do.